# What is this seed/fruit from a tree in Greece called?

Tags: food-identification

I picked this up from a tree in Greece, where the landform was plain. It is about 2.5cm (see other objects for scale). I would like ot know its name

[image: seed/fruit next to ruler, leaf, and euro coin]

Comment: where are you located? Did you find this on a random tree or bush, or did you buy it at a food market? Is your question whether it's safe to eat, or do you just want to know its English name so you can find recipes that use it?

Comment: I picked it up from a tree.I just want to know its name.

Comment: Can you put something else in the picture for scale?

Comment: It is 2.5 cm tall if that helps

Comment: This may be better asked on Gardening.

Comment: Are you even sure it's edible? I think I've seen it, but not used for human consumption.

Comment: Regarding @KateGregory initial comment, what was the location of the tree? (country, landform...)

Comment: It's from Greece and the landform is plain.

Comment: It reminds me vaguely of an olive or caper berry

Answer (score 2):

This might be [brier](https://www.google.ro/search?q=brier&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=eSdMU_TVJaHoywOe2YKoDQ&ved=0CFsQsAQ&biw=1920&bih=979) you're talking about.
It's hard to tell based on only that picture... it may be a type of cherry, but when I saw the post, I instantly pictured it to be a type of brier.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks clearly like a cherry, but might not be an edible one. The fruit is a bit ambiguous, but the leaf is a perfect match. The stem is also very telling.

A clarification on language: The sweet black cherry sold in the market is not the only fruit called "cherry". There are many types of cherry, and while I am quite sure the picture depicts one of these, I can't promise that it is a tasty, edible cherry. It is certainly not the sweet black type. It may be a chokecherry, as mentioned in the comments; botanically, this would still be a cherry, just like a cantaloupe is still a melon. Or it may be any other of a number of edible and inedible cherries.

Comment: could be a chokecherry though

Comment: My thought exactly,but its too small for a cherry.

Comment: @user24364 : we have nothing to give it scale ... you need a ruler in the picture or a coin or something else of a standard size.

Comment: It's 2.5 cm tall.

Comment: There are many different types of cherry. I cannot promise that the picture is of one of the types which are normally eaten. A chokecherry is, botanically speaking, as much of a cherry as the ones we eat. Of course, if somebody can make a more differentiated identification than mine, it would be good.

Comment: "It's a cherry" might imply to a lot of people that it's an edible one, so I added a bit at the beginning to be safe.